# Integrate $\sqrt \frac{x}{1-x} $

Tags: calculus, integration

What would be the best method to integrate $\sqrt \frac{x}{1-x} $ ?

I tried the substitution $1-x=t $ that makes the inner fraction $(1/t-1)$.But after that not getting any simple method.Please help me out...

Comment: Try $x=\sin^2\theta$. Probably not best, but it works.

Comment: @AndréNicolas After seeing your comment I tried it out myself. as you said, not the most fun, especially with justifying the domain on the change of variable in order to drop an absolute value, but not as terrible as I might have thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running with Andre's excellent suggestion to use $x=\sin^2 \theta$ (notice the immediate simplification of the denominator!) we get the form
$$\int \sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}} dx = \int \frac{d\theta}{\sin(2\theta)}\sqrt{\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}} =\int\tan\theta\sin(2\theta)d\theta$$

Note that above we require that $x\in [0,1)$ and also that $0\leq \theta< \frac{\pi}{2}$ and thus we drop the absolute value (the domain restriction on $\theta$ allows the substitution to be a function, satisfying our needs)
$$\int\tan\theta\sin(2\theta)d\theta = \theta-\frac{\sin(2\theta)}{2}$$

> $$= \;\arcsin(\sqrt x)-\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt x$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. One may perform the change of variable
$$
u=\sqrt \frac{x}{1-x},\quad x= \frac{u^2}{u^2+1}, \quad dx= \frac{2u}{(u^2+1)^2}du,
$$ giving
$$
\int\sqrt \frac{x}{1-x}\:dx=2\int \frac{u^2}{(u^2+1)^2}du=-\frac{u}{1+u^2}+\arctan u+C
$$ or

> $$
> \int\sqrt \frac{x}{1-x}\:dx=-\sqrt{x(1-x)}+\arctan \left( \sqrt \frac{x}{1-x}\right)+C.
> $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Let $u=\sqrt {1-x} $, then $u^2 = 1-x $ ,$x = 1-u^2$ ,$dx =-2udu $

The integral will be $\frac{\sqrt{1-u^2}}{u}\times-2udu = -2\sqrt{1-u^2}du$.

Try use trigonometric function to substitute $u$.

Easy to show that: $-2\int \sqrt{1-u^2}du = -u \sqrt{1-u^2}- \arcsin(u) + C = -\sqrt{x-x^2} -\arcsin(\sqrt{1-x})+C.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Substitute $$1-x= t^2$$ You will get something like $$\int \sqrt {(1-t^2)} dx$$
Then substitute $ t= sin(\theta)$

Comment: Check the sign of the integral plz it should be $1-t^2$. What's more, you substitution is identical to me after I pose it. Try to find another way to substitute x

Comment: Yes, you are right. My mistake. Corrected it. I didn't see your answer before posting.

Comment: Yep but the essence of Math is to inspire your creativity. When you have found someone's solution is identical to yours, you can try to find another way to solve. That's so-called creativity.

Comment: Alternative solution for this problem is to try to use my favorite series expansion "talyor series" to do integral. Hopefully you can find the solution.